# Hibernate / Order By / Rownum / Incorrect Pagination Results Returbed

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, criteria

I am using a criteria query with order by for pagination with a page size of 10.
For example, for a "getResultList() of the query" of 20 rows the:
The first page displays 10 results ("setFirstResult(0) , set MaxResults(10)"-->used for pagination).

The second page displays 10 results (setFirstResult(10) , set MaxResults(10)-->used for paginatio)

```
    The problem is that the second page contains also some results from the first page.
    After checking the generated SQL I noticed that the order by is missing from the outer query:

//Criteria Code  
Query q=..              
          query.setFirstResult(paginate.getFirst()).setMaxResults(paginate.getRows());
result = query.getResultList();
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
```

First page generated SQL:

```
      select
               *
            from
                ( select
                    usernotifi0_.USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as USER_NOTIFICATION_1_47_,
                    usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED as ARCHIVED2_47_,
                    usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as NOTIFICATION_CASE_4_47_,
                    usernotifi0_.READ as READ3_47_,
                    usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID as USER_INFORMATION_I5_47_ 
                from
                    USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE usernotifi0_ 
                inner join
                    NOTIFICATION_CASE notificati1_ 
                        on usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID=notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID 
                inner join
                    COUNTRY country3_ 
                        on notificati1_.MAIN_MEMBER_STATE=country3_.COUNTRY_KEY 
                where
                    usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID=161 
                    and usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED=0
                    and notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_STATUS<>'TRASH'
                order by
                    country3_.COUNTRY_KEY desc ) 
            where
                rownum <= 10 

        Second page generated SQL:
           select     *
            from
                ( select
                    row_.*,
                    rownum rownum_ 
                from
                    ( select
                        usernotifi0_.USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as USER_NOTIFICATION_1_47_,
                        usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED as ARCHIVED2_47_,
                        usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as NOTIFICATION_CASE_4_47_,
                        usernotifi0_.READ as READ3_47_,
                        usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID as USER_INFORMATION_I5_47_ 
                    from
                        USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE usernotifi0_ 
                    inner join
                        NOTIFICATION_CASE notificati1_ 
                            on usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID=notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID 
                    inner join
                        COUNTRY country3_ 
                            on notificati1_.MAIN_MEMBER_STATE=country3_.COUNTRY_KEY 
                    where
                        usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID=161 
                        and usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED=0
                        and notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_STATUS<>'TRASH'
                    order by
                        country3_.COUNTRY_KEY desc ) row_ 
                where
                    rownum <= 20
                ) 
            where
```

### rownum_ > 10

For page1: I modified the query to return the unique notification_case_id and the rownum for a page size of 20:

```
select
        NOTIFICATION_CASE_4_47_,rownum
    from
        ( select
            usernotifi0_.USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as USER_NOTIFICATION_1_47_,
            usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED as ARCHIVED2_47_,
            usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID as NOTIFICATION_CASE_4_47_,
            usernotifi0_.READ as READ3_47_,
            usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID as USER_INFORMATION_I5_47_ 
        from
            USER_NOTIFICATION_CASE usernotifi0_ 
        inner join
            NOTIFICATION_CASE notificati1_ 
                on usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID=notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID 
        where
            usernotifi0_.USER_INFORMATION_ID=41 
            and usernotifi0_.ARCHIVED=0
            and notificati1_.NOTIFICATION_STATUS<>'TRASH'
        order by
            notificati1_.MAIN_MEMBER_STATE desc ) 
    where
        rownum <= 20
```

The result is (case_id rownum):

```
(764 1) (681 2) (704 3) (765 4) (284 5)
(601    6)
(683    7)
(241    8)
(268    9)
(270    10)
(467    11)
(514    12)
(541    13)
(586    14)
(276    15)
(367    16)
(368    17)
(515    18)
(459    19)
(584    20)
```

For a page1 the result of a  page size 10 the result is:

```
(764    1)
(681    2)
(704    3)
(765    4)
(284    5)
(241    6)
(268    7)
(270    8)
(467    9)
(514    10)
```

The results returned in both cases should be the same for the first 10 rows but they are not. For rownum 6 the results start to differ.

Comment: How to make the pagination in Criteria to work. That is the results to be ordered correctly. I am thinking of mapping the results to a database view object.

Comment: The outer query doesn't need an `ORDER BY` because the inner query has `row_.*, rownum rownum_`.  This means that the inner query sorts the rows, takes the first 20, ***and*** assigns the value from `rownum` *(with values 1 to 20)* to the column `rownum_`.  The outer query then takes the last 10 rows based on that computed column.  To debug this, I recommend the following: Show us the results for page 1 with a page size of 20, then page 1 with a page size of 10, then page 2 with a page size of 10.

Comment: What I ***think*** you'll probably find from that is that the first 20 rows all share the same `COUNTRY_KEY` value.  If that's the case then you should `ORDER BY` more than one column.  Enough columns that every row can be uniquely identified and so has a deterministic position in the ordered set.  Perhaps `ORDER BY country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC, usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID`?  Which combination of columns is most appropriate will depend on your data and your needs.

Comment: thanks. I updated my post on the top. When I use both of them ORDER BY country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC,usernotifi0_.NOTIFICATION_CASE_ID , I do not get duplicate results in the second page but the ordering is wrong. The country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC is not applied to all results. The results in the first 20 rows do not share the same country value

Comment: Your new query doesn't have `ORDER BY country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC` in it *any where*.  So why would such an order be applied?  Perhaps you meant to use `ORDER BY country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC, notificati1_.MAIN_MEMBER_STATE desc`?

Comment: I have updated the Criteria query in order to remove the second join in the initial query. In the new query, the country3_.COUNTRY_KEY DESC is the notificati1_.MAIN_MEMBER_STATE desc. The problem though remains the same

Comment: Then the solution probably remains the same.  I said you need to use `ORDER BY x, y, z` not just `ORDER BY x`.  I also asked for result of your pagination queries, but you gave results to something else *(not including all the relevant columns from your real query)*.  You're taking short cuts, and not paying attention to details.  I'm sorry, I'm going to stop assisting you now.

Comment: Hi MatBailie. I did not display the results for brevity.I was reordering the list in the controller. I removed it and added the double order by. It works  fine now. thanks